# Why does batch treat an array entry different from singular?

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I have the following (simplified etc):

```
@echo off
set searchStr="AAAA"

set workingPaths[0]="C:\Docs\Me\"

set x=0

::Loop1
if defined workingPaths[%x%] (
    set currPath=%%workingPaths[%x%]%%
    rem set currPath="C:\Docs\Me\"

    call echo Searching in: %currPath%

    for %%f in (%currPath%*.doc*) do (
        findstr /s /m /I /c:%searchStr% "%%f"
    )

    set /a x+=1
    GOTO :Loop1
)
```

It works perfectly fine if I were to switch the currPath to a singular assignment (where rem is currently), but won't work if the currPath is assigned out of the array.

The subsequent echo is identical regardless of whether currPath is set from the array or the singular assignment.

Anyone any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, might have sussed it myself - see update above

Comment: I've rolled back your latest edit. Please, if you have a solution to your issue, submit it as an answer, in the appropriate place. If you're not willing to do that, please delete your question, as there's no point in having a question which doesn't require solving! Also, are you sure that you're reading a `doc` file with `findstr.exe`?

Comment: The variable `currPath` contains the literal string `%workingPaths[0]%`, which is processed by the `for` loop. You would also need `call` to extract the expected path string `C:\Docs\Me\ `also there, but `call for` (like also `call if`) is not allowed. Therefore, enable and use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to avoid the slow and problematic `call`…

Comment: Cheers Compo, OK - will be sure to keep answers separate in future.Yep, it does search for a .doc - but doesn't exclude .docx

[Although I there is something in the back of my mind about docx in findstr from years ago I can't remember the details]

Thanks mofi and aschipfl for a good succinct answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would perform this task a little differently, in that I'd try to better utilise the built-in options of `findstr.exe`. I would build a listing of the `workingPaths` and pass those to a single `findstr.exe` instance, using its `/D` option.

Example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem Script defined variables [please do not modify].
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set workingPaths[) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "findStr=%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe"
Set "dirList="

Rem User defined variables [modify as necessary]
Set "searchStr=AAAA"
Set "searchGlob=*.doc"
Set "workingPaths[0]=C:\Docs\Me"
Set "workingPaths[1]=C:\Users\Me\Documents"
Set "workingPaths[2]=C:\Users\Me\Desktop"

Rem Directory list builder [please do not modify]
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set workingPaths[) 2>NUL"'
) Do If Not Defined dirList (Set "dirList="%%~H"") Else (
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%I In ('"!dirList!"') Do (EndLocal
        Set "dirList=%%~I;"%%~H""))
If Not Defined dirList Exit /B

Rem Main search command [please do not modify]
%findStr% /D:%dirList% /I /L /M /S "%searchStr%" "%searchGlob%"

Rem Optional commands for GUI usage puposes only [remove as necessary]
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: What is/are the advantage(s) of doing it this way?

Is it substantially quicker?

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
set currPath=%%workingPaths[%x%]%%
```

to

```
set currPath=!workingPaths[%x%]!
```

and its working... albeit it doesn't seem to like iterating the last array entry ('cos I was stupid and typo'd it!).

Leaving a final working solution of:

```
@echo off
set searchStr="AAAA"

set workingPaths[0]="C:\Docs\Me\"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=0

::Loop1
if defined workingPaths[%x%] (
    set currPath=!workingPaths[%x%]!
    rem set currPath="C:\Docs\Me\"

    call echo Searching in: %currPath%

    for %%f in (%currPath%*.doc*) do (
        findstr /s /m /I /c:%searchStr% "%%f"
    )

    set /a x+=1
    GOTO :Loop1
)
```

Comment: Well, how did you enable delayed expansion?

Comment: Ah, yep, it was added in below setting the arrays

Comment: Ahm, I was talking about `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, which must be stated somewhere in your script for your answer to work; you should mention it in your answer for it to become complete…

Comment: Yeap, I know you were talking about setting that local, was just giving a quick n dirty answer!
Added in the working version if that helps make it clearer.